# How to check dependencies on user's PC while installing Electron app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I am new to electron js and have certain questions regarding the build of the electron app. I am building a react-electron app for desktop in linux/ubuntu that uses docker and ngrok. Now I want to check on user's PC that whether docker and ngrok are present or not before the elsectro app is installed. If the dependencies mentioned are not present on user's PC it should show a message that install these softwares before proceeding along with commands provided to the user...as it happens in most of the applications installations out there.
How could I do this using electron app that uses react on linux.

This is my pacakage.json file:

```
{
 "name": "qcloud-test",
 "productName": "Qcloud",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "main": "public/main.js",
 "homepage": "./",
 "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
 "author": {
 "name": "Qcloud dev",
 "email": "qcloud@gmail.com"
  },
 "description": "QCloud Test",
 "dependencies": {
 "@electron/remote": "^1.0.2",
 "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
 "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
 "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
 "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
 "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
 "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta1",
 "child_process": "^1.0.2",
 "dockerode": "^3.3.5",
 "electron-is-dev": "^1.2.0",
 "express": "^4.18.2",
 "express-async-handler": "^1.2.0",
 "ioredis": "^5.3.2",
 "ngrok": "^4.3.3",
 "pg": "^8.11.1",
 "qlu-20-ui-library": "^1.1.117",
 "react": "^17.0.1",
 "react-bootstrap": "^2.8.0",
 "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
 "react-redux": "^8.1.2",
 "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
 "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
 "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
 "systeminformation": "^5.18.7",
 "uuid": "^9.0.0",
 "web-vitals": "^0.2.4",
 "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
 "scripts": {
 "start": "react-scripts start",
 "prebuild": "node src/setup.js",
 "build": "react-scripts build",
 "test": "react-scripts test",
 "eject": "react-scripts eject",
 "electron:serve": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm run electron:start\"",
 "electron:build": "rm -rf dist && rm -rf build && npm run build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js",
 "electron:start": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron .",
 "electron:package:linux": "npm run build && electron-builder -l -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js"
  },
 "build": {
 "extends": null,
 "appId": "com.electron.myapp",
 "productName": "QCloud-Test",
 "files": [
 "dist/**/*",
 "build/**/*",
 "node_modules/**/*",
 "package.json"
    ],
 "extraResources": [
 "/snap/bin/ngrok"
    ],
 "directories": {
 "buildResources": "assets"
    },
 "mac": {
 "target": "dmg"
    },
 "win": {
 "target": [
        {
 "target": "nsis",
 "arch": [
 "x64", 
 "ia32"
          ]
        },
        {
 "target": "zip",
 "arch": [
 "x64",
 "ia32"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
 "linux": {
 "target": "deb",
 "category": "Development",
 "icon": "build/logo.png"
    },
 "deb": {
 "depends": [
 "docker",
 "ngrok",
 "gconf2"
 
      ]
    }

  },
 "eslintConfig": {
 "extends": [
 "react-app",
 "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
 "browserslist": [
 ">0.2%",
 "not dead",
 "not op_mini all"
  ],
 "devDependencies": {
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
 "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
 "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
 "electron": "^11.5.0",
 "electron-builder": "^22.14.13",
 "electronmon": "^2.0.2",
 "prettier": "^2.2.1",
 "wait-on": "^5.3.0"
  }
}
```

Note: I had used fpm and beforeInstall in linux properties to run a bash script and check the dependencies before the app is installed but it gives me the following error:

• loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
⨯ Invalid configuration object. electron-builder 22.14.13 has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.linux has an unknown property 'fpm'. These properties are valid:
  object { appId?, artifactName?, asar?, asarUnpack?, category?, compression?, cscKeyPassword?, cscLink?, defaultArch?, description?, desktop?, detectUpdateChannel?, electronUpdaterCompatibility?, executableArgs?, executableName?, extraFiles?, extraResources?, fileAssociations?, files?, forceCodeSigning?, generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels?, icon?, maintainer?, mimeTypes?, packageCategory?, protocols?, publish?, releaseInfo?, synopsis?, target?, vendor? }
  How to fix:

  1. Open https://www.electron.build/configuration/linux
  2. Search the option name on the page (or type in into Search to find across the docs).

  - Not found? The option was deprecated or not exists (check spelling).
    * Found? Check that the option in the appropriate place. e.g. "title" only in the "dmg", not in the root.
    failedTask=build stackTrace=ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. electron-builder 22.14.13 has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
- configuration.linux has an unknown property 'fpm'. These properties are valid:
  object { appId?, artifactName?, asar?, asarUnpack?, category?, compression?, cscKeyPassword?, cscLink?, defaultArch?, description?, desktop?, detectUpdateChannel?, electronUpdaterCompatibility?, executableArgs?, executableName?, extraFiles?, extraResources?, fileAssociations?, files?, forceCodeSigning?, generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels?, icon?, maintainer?, mimeTypes?, packageCategory?, protocols?, publish?, releaseInfo?, synopsis?, target?, vendor? }
  How to fix:

  1. Open https://www.electron.build/configuration/linux
  2. Search the option name on the page (or type in into Search to find across the docs).

  - Not found? The option was deprecated or not exists (check spelling).
    * Found? Check that the option in the appropriate place. e.g. "title" only in the "dmg", not in the root.
    at validate (/home/shireen/Desktop/qcloud1.0/qCloud-electron-app/node_modules/@develar/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:86:11)
    at Object.validateConfig (/home/shireen/Desktop/qcloud1.0/qCloud-electron-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/util/config.ts:240:3)
    at Packager._build (/home/shireen/Desktop/qcloud1.0/qCloud-electron-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:342:5)
    at Packager.build (/home/shireen/Desktop/qcloud1.0/qCloud-electron-app/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/packager.ts:337:12)
    at Object.executeFinally (/home/shireen/Desktop/qcloud1.0/qCloud-electron-app/node_modules/builder-util/src/promise.ts:12:14)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! qcloud-test@0.1.0 electron:build: `rm -rf dist && rm -rf build && npm run build && electron-builder -c.extraMetadata.main=build/main.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the qcloud-test@0.1.0 electron:build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/shireen/.npm/_logs/2023-09-06T13_58_15_592Z-debug.log

The command I am using to build the electron .deb file is:
npm run electron:build

Kindly provode me with an accurate solution of how could I achieve the above goal?
Thanks in advance.